# How to remove XCode9 "Conversion to swift 4 is available" warning?

Tags: swift, xcode

I had to convert my project manually since Xcode would crash when I tried to use the migration tool. Now that that's done I'd like to remove the warning from my project. I can't see any obvious way to do it and clicking on the warning immediately crashes Xcode which is why I ended up manually converting to begin with.

Comment: I submitted one regarding the crash but I haven't heard a response yet.

Comment: Are you saying the code *is* Swift 4? If so, have you set it to be that in the project settings (Project, Build Settings, Swift Compiler - Language, Swift Language Version)?

Comment: That did it. Thank you. Add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Added. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When manually converting - not using the migration tool - to Swift 4, remember to set the project setting to be Swift 4. (Project | Build Settings | Swift Compiler - Language | Swift Language Version.)

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't help

Comment: @AlexanderYakovlev, this question was asked/answered over 1.5 years ago and applies to Xcode 9! Are you talking.... Xcode 11? Swift 5.0? Swift 5.1? And please, don't just post a 3 word sentence 94 if you wish to count the contraction). That's rude! Beyond the fact that this is an accepted answer - so it obviously *did* help someone - post a detailed question, possibly with enough to duplicate (if that's possible) and then post a comment here with a link to it. I'd be most happy to try to help! Thanks.